# Trouble Counting Subseq of a String Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to use the function count to tell me how many occurrences of a "<script>" tag there are but I can't seem to get it working. My code:

```
(count "<script>" "<p>Hello World</p><script>javascript goes here</script>" :key #'string :test #'equal)
```

I can't seem to find much examples of it but I did find one for remove and I figured they are similar. How can I get this to return 1 not 0?

Comment: Do you want to count overlapping instances?  E.g., if you want to count "aaa" should you get "baaaab" return 1 or 2?  There's at most 1 distinct occurrence, but there are two occurrences if they can overlap.

Comment: No overlapping instances but I think I'm going to use an HTML parser.

Comment: @phile That's definitely a more robust solution.

Comment: @phile that said, if you interested, there was a very similar question asked just shortly before yours: [A function which identifies how many times a string is included in another on in lisp](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35058220/1281433).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Count`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_countc.htm) only counts single elements that match (so you could use it to count the #\a characters for example, but not substrings). For counting substrings you'll want something like this:

```
(defun count-substrings (substring string)
  (loop
    with sub-length = (length substring)
    for i from 0 to (- (length string) sub-length)
    when (string= string substring
                  :start1 i :end1 (+ i sub-length))
    count it))
```

Of course counting html tags like this is pretty error prone. You'll probably want to use an actual parser.

Comment: I'll look into parsers. Which one do you recommend, "cl-html-parse"?

Comment: I haven't used that myself, but I tried it out quickly and it seems to work pretty well and is very easy to use. It might not be the most efficient one for very large documents (since it parses it into a list), but for smaller fragments it should be good. If you need to parse large docs, try [cl-html5-parser](https://github.com/copyleft/cl-html5-parser).

Comment: You don't want to use `subseq`. That would be VERY expensive. Note that `string=` has keyword parameters for start and end...

Comment: @jkiiski How do I navigate the build dom with cl-html5-parser. If I have the following code `(html5-parser:parse-html5-fragment (drakma:http-request "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_heaviest_people") :dom :xmls)` how can I get the information under the <body> tag? Do you know of any good tutorials using the parser?

Comment: @phile If you're using `:dom :xmls`, you should see [xmls](https://common-lisp.net/project/xmls/) (which works together with `cl-html5-parser`). The tags are basically encoded in lists like `("name" (attributes) children*)`. You'll want to recursively search throught the children. I made a [quick example](http://paste.lisp.org/+6K5N) for finding the first occurance of a given tag. If you need more help with it, I suppose it's best if you make another question for it.

Comment: @jkiiski I figured out how to navigate with XML a bit but am stuck trying to get a certain column of the table. If you have the time, I asked another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35065686/navigating-a-webpage-using-xmls-common-lisp

Answer (score 3):

A concise solution using the primitive function [`search`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_search.htm#search):

```
(defun count-substring(substring string)
  (do ((count -1 (+ count 1))
       (position -1 (search substring string :start2 (1+ position))))
      ((null position) count)))
```

*Edited*
In the first version count started from 0, but this is incorrect.

Comment: The concept is there, but the details are not right.  This will return 1 when there is no substring.  You need to set the initial value of `position` to `(search ... :start2 0)` (or omit the `start2` argument entirely).

Comment: @acelent, many thanks, I've corrected the answer (by starting count from -1).