# Navigating a webpage using html5-parser and xmls Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to get the first row under the column with the title "Name" so for example for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_heaviest_people I want to return the name "Jon Brower Minnoch". My code so far is as follows, but I think there must be a more general way of getting the name:

```
(defun find-tag (tag doc)
 (when (listp doc)
  (when (string= (xmls:node-name doc) tag)
   (return-from find-tag doc))
  (loop for child in (xmls:node-children doc)
   for find = (find-tag tag child)
   when find do (return-from find-tag find)))
  nil)

(defun parse-list-website (url)
  (second (second (second (third (find-tag "td" (html5-parser:parse-html5 (drakma:http-request url) :dom :xmls)))))))
```

and then to call the function:

```
(parse-list-website "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_heaviest_people")
```

I am not very good with xmls and don't know how to get an get a td under a certain column header.

Comment: Do note that xmls is an XML parser, and HTML isn't required to be legal XML.  Even the variants that are (XHTML) often have malformed content that HTML parsers can handle, but that an XML parser should complain about.

Comment: For instance, if you download the HTML of that wikipedia article and try to parse it with xmls, you get back **nil**, presumably because it's not well-formed XML. [CL-HTML-PARSE](http://www.cliki.net/cl-html-parse) on the other hand, returns a result.

Comment: So far it seems to parse, I just can't really navigate the returned data structure. It says its a html5 parser.

Comment: @phile I'm not sure where you see that.  On [its webpage](https://common-lisp.net/project/xmls/), I see "XMLS, a simple XML parser for Common Lisp".  If you're using a different library, could you provide a link?

Comment: I'm using html5-parser to convert it into xml.

Comment: The example `find-tag` I gave only looks for the first occurance of the given tag, so you can use it to find unique elements (body), but not ones that appear multiple times. You'll want to modify it to look for an id instead of tag name. @JoshuaTaylor He is using cl-html5-parser that produces output compatible with xmls.

Comment: @jkiiski OK, that adds some clarification, but I think the title of the question probably shouldn't be **Navigating a webpage using XMLS Common Lisp**, then.

Comment: @jkiiski I don't know how to find attributes using xmls. If I wanted to find class="headerSort" inside a tr class how could I do that?

Comment: You can use `xmls:node-attrs` to get the attributes of a node as an alist. Replace the `(string= (xmls:node-name doc) tag)` with something like `(string= (second (assoc "class" (xmls:node-attrs doc) :test #'string=)) the-class-you-want)`. Or add that condition along with the node-name, whatever suits your situation. I'll write an answer later when I have more time (unless someone else does first).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The elements in the document returned by `html5-parser:parse-html5` are in the form:

```
("name" (attribute-alist) &rest children)
```

You could access the parts with the standard list manipulation functions, but `xmls` also provides functions `node-name`, `node-attrs` and `node-children` to access the three parts. It's a little bit clearer to use those. **Edit: there are also functions `xmlrep-attrib-value`, to get the value of an attribute and `xmlrep-tagmatch` to match the tag name.** The children are either plain strings, or elements in the same format.

So for example, a html document with a 2x2 table would look like this:

```
(defparameter *doc*
  '("html" ()
     ("head" ()
       ("title" ()
         "Some title"))
     ("body" ()
       ("table" (("class" "some-class"))
         ("tr" (("class" "odd"))
           ("td" () "Some string")
           ("td" () "Another string"))
         ("tr" (("class" "even"))
           ("td" () "Third string")
           ("td" () "Fourth string"))))))
```

In order to traverse the dom-tree, lets define a recursive depth-first search like this (note that the `if-let` depends on the `alexandria` library (either import it, or change it to `alexandria:if-let`)):

```
(defun find-tag (predicate doc &optional path)
  (when (funcall predicate doc path)
    (return-from find-tag doc))

  (when (listp doc)
    (let ((path (cons doc path)))
      (dolist (child (xmls:node-children doc))
        (if-let ((find (find-tag predicate child path)))
          (return-from find-tag find))))))
```

It's called with a predicate function and a document. The predicate function gets called with two arguments; the element being matched and a list of its ancestors. In order to find the first `<td>`, you could do this:

```
(find-tag (lambda (el path)
            (declare (ignore path))
            (and (listp el)
                 (xmls:xmlrep-tagmatch "td" el)))
          *doc*)
; => ("td" NIL "Some string")
```

Or to find the first `<td>` in the even row:

```
(find-tag (lambda (el path)
            (and (listp el)
                 (xmls:xmlrep-tagmatch "td" el)
                 (string= (xmls:xmlrep-attrib-value "class" (first path))
                          "even")))
          *doc*)
; => ("td" NIL "Third string")
```

Getting the second `<td>` on the even row would require something like this:

```
(let ((matches 0))
  (find-tag (lambda (el path)
              (when (and (listp el)
                         (xmls:xmlrep-tagmatch "td" el)
                         (string= (xmls:xmlrep-attrib-value "class" (first path))
                                  "even"))
                (incf matches))
              (= matches 2))
            *doc*))
```

You could define a helper function to find the nth tag:

```
(defun find-nth-tag (n tag doc)
  (let ((matches 0))
    (find-tag (lambda (el path)
                (declare (ignore path))
                (when (and (listp el)
                           (xmls:xmlrep-tagmatch tag el))
                  (incf matches))
                (= matches n))
              doc)))
(find-nth-tag 2 "td" *doc*) ; => ("td" NIL "Another string")
(find-nth-tag 4 "td" *doc*) ; => ("td" NIL "Fourth string")
```

You might want to have a simple helper to get the text of a node:

```
(defun node-text (el)
  (if (listp el)
      (first (xmls:node-children el))
      el))
```

You could define similiar helpers to do whatever you need to do in your application. Using these, the example you gave would look like this:

```
(defparameter *doc*
  (html5-parser:parse-html5
   (drakma:http-request "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_the_heaviest_people")
   :dom :xmls))

(node-text (find-nth-tag 1 "a" (find-nth-tag 1 "td" *doc*)))
; => "Jon Brower Minnoch"
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation. I was pretty confused by the xmls documentation.